# Ubuntu Lenovo ThinkPad Battery Drains in Suspend/Hibernate

Tags: ubuntu, battery, lenovo-laptop, thinkpad, suspend

I recently purchased a Lenovo ThinkPad L14 Gen 2 with Ubuntu 21.0 pre-installed. I've been having a problem that when I shut the lid of the laptop and enter a suspended state, the laptop still consumes significant power. After a few hours in its suspended state, the battery dies. This can be very frustrating because when I restart the laptop, my state is gone. It's a laptop, it's meant to be closed and carried around for at least a day in suspension without charging...

First, I've used `gnome-tweaks` to check that my laptop is indeed set to suspend when the lid is shut.

Next, I read some guides on Lenovo laptops with Ubuntu installed and it seems the problem may be incompatibility between Windows Modern Standby and Linux. (I'm not entirely sure this is the issue since my computer is Ubuntu pre-installed. But perhaps Lenovo still uses Windows Modern Standby since the default configuration for this laptop model is with Windows installed.) Here are the guides that I read: [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/joj9i8/solution_to_sleep_battery_drain_on_linux/), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012727/sleep-mode-consumes-as-much-as-battery-as-when-laptop-is-in-use), and [here](https://delta-xi.net/blog/#056).

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a guide for my specific device. However, it seems the general issue is changing the BIOS settings for "Sleep State" to "Linux". So I tried booting into BIOS to changing this setting. This setting is supposed to be in the BIOS menu under Config > Power. However, on my machine this setting isn't accessible.

So now I'm at a bit of a loss as to what to try next. Does anyone with more experience with these hardware settings have a suggestion/solution? Has anyone run into this issue the same/similar device as mine?

Comment: See in the Lenovo Support Site if there are new Power Drivers for your system, and perhaps even BIOS. It is not hibernating properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You state, "when I shut the lid of the laptop and enter a suspended state," and by default, Ubuntu does not enable *Hibernate*, [but uses *Suspend*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3369/what-is-the-difference-between-hibernate-and-suspend), equivalent to MS *Sleep*. *Suspend* puts the processor into a low-power state, and *appears* to be shut down, but keeps all work in RAM, to be reopened very quickly. Yes, that *does* consume battery power, but unless *Hibernate* is enabled, the only thing the OS can do, when battery is low, is to perform a full shutdown, losing all work.

However, it [may be feasible to enable *Hibernate*](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/08/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-21-10/). This does not work on all PC's. **Before enabling *Hibernate*, make a disk image, using dd or other tool, since a problem may occur making it impossible to boot!**

- To check if *Hibernate*  is already implemented on your PC, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to open *Terminal*, enter `systemctl hibernate`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. If all goes well, the machine will shut down, and upon restarting, all your work will be intact.
- If it is not, then you will need to follow the full tutorial above to:

  - Ensure there is a large enough *swap* area to hold all RAM.
  - Edit *grub2* to resume after shutdown form the *swap* area.
  - Create a *swap* file and set permissions.
  - Create a *config* file to control rebooting.
  - Add *Hibernate* to power options.
  - Set the *lid close* action to *Hibernate*.

Per @Matthews: "[A]fter doing the above steps, the system needs to updated to specifically hibernate on the lid shutting, not just suspend. That can be done with [[this] guide](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/05/lid-close-behavior-ubuntu-20-04/)".

One can gather, from the length of this process, that Ubuntu developers do not think well of *Hibernate*. Perhaps it's considered a security risk, though on a personal laptop, that might not be a major consideration.

Comment: Thanks for this! Fortunately, I did have hibernate on my system and this seems to have worked for me. Also after doing the above steps, the system needs to updated to specifically hibernate on the lid shutting, not just suspend. That can be done with the following guide: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/05/lid-close-behavior-ubuntu-20-04/

Comment: @matthews, +1 for completion of instructions, which I'll quote and add to answer.

Answer (score 0):

my machine (Thinkpad x1 yoga gen2), drained battery on Hibernate mode as well. so after 2 days in hibernate state it would drain the battery from 30% down to  complete 0%, up until I need to declare time settings in bios, which was pretty frustrating.

I fixed the issue with disabling `Wake-on-Lan` setting.
ref to docs [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate), look for the `Wake-on-LAN` (section 6.3):

[look here for how to disable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288717/how-to-disable-wake-on-lan)